# ngSwitch on Angular Form validation

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I´m new on Angular and i trying to do a Form Validation on a SwitchCase.
On the SwitchCase 0 i have a form and What i want is for that information to be submited and at the same time the view change to SwitchCase 1.

The Form Validation works perfect, but when i add the function `siguiente()` i get an error `Form submission canceled because the form is not connected` What i´m doing wrong?

Here is the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y4hqgw

Answer (score 0):

you are closing form tag in wrong manner you need to open and close form for all steps like

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
<br />

<div [ngSwitch]="variable">
  <form (ngSubmit)="guardar(forma)" #forma="ngForm">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'0'">Paso1

      <div class="form-group row ">
        <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Nombre</label>
        <div class="col-8">

          <input class="form-control"
                 type="text"
                 placeholder="Nombre"
                 name="Nombre"
                 [(ngModel)]="usuario.nombre"
                 minlenght="5"
                 required
                 #nombre="ngModel"><!--La variable local hace referencia al form control-->

        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="siguiente()" [disabled]="!forma.valid">Siguiente</button>





  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'1'">Paso2<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="anterior()">Atras</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="siguiente()">Siguiente</button></div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'2'">Paso3<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="anterior()">Atras</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="siguiente()">Siguiente</button></div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'3'">Paso4<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="anterior()">Atras</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="siguiente()">Siguiente</button></div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'4'">Paso5<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="anterior()">Atras</button>
        </div>
</form>
</div>
```

it was showing an error because all the ngSwitchCase was not inside the form tag. and type = "submit" is usually used for form submission.

Comment: How can i see changes on the stack? It appers the same

Comment: in your form change button line to this <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="siguiente()" [disabled]="!forma.valid">Siguiente</button>

Comment: Yeah, doing that removes the warning but the information of the form does not sent it

Comment: yes because you need to set your form tag to all button you were closing your form tag in the wrong manner and using type = button on next step too. so you need to close form after all the steps i have updated please check

Comment: I copied your solution on stack, but its the same, i dont get the values of the form

Comment: this is because you are using (click) event again on every button if you remove that it will execute.

Comment: And what can i do to pass over the views instead of that click event?

Comment: for that, you can change the type=" button"  if you want to execute in the click event.